# View boost::optional content while native debug in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, lldb, boost-optional

I only tried at 2.3.3 studio. Haven't tried new 3.0

- Haven't found any plugins that can help
- Tried to cast in lldb console. Have some errors there, don't know how to do that properly

So, is there any solutions? How you deal with such problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've struggled with the same problem and found the solution just recently.
Works on AS3.0, haven't tried on older versions
Try to evaluate this expression (right-click in code or debug windows during debug, or Alt+F8)

```
<your base type> val = <your variable>.get()
val
```

For example, if you have an optional variable named timestamp, write

```
int64_t val = timestamp.get()
val
```